# How to modify Grid RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in WPF during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a program that is a simple puzzle game - all but one cells are filled with buttons and you have to order them properly by moving them around using the only one empty cell. The first version was a 3x3 grid with 8 buttons + one invisible. However, now I want to enable users to change the number of rows and columns. I need to use sliders to manipulate height and width. Unfortunately, I have no idea how can I manipulate the grid during runtime. Here's a screenshot of what I have at the moment: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless WPF is far different from Silverlight, can't you just programmatically alter the column/grid definitions?

(just warning, writing this in notepad as I don't have visual studio with me to check, so I'm just going by memory)

```
myGrid.Columns.Clear();
myGrid.Rows.Clear();

int buttonNumber = 0;
double buttonWidth = GridWidth / numberOfColumns;
double buttonHeight = GridHeight / numberOfRows;

for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < numberOfColumns; columnNumber++)
{
    var column = new ColumnDefinition();
    myGrid.Columns.Add(column);

    for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < numberOfRows; rowNumber++)
    {
        var row = new RowDefinition();
        myGrid.Rows.Add(row);

        var button = new Button();
        button.Content = ++buttonNumber;
        button.Width = buttonWidth;
        button.Height = buttonHeight;
        Grid.SetColumn(button, columnNumber);
        Grid.SetRow(button, rowNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there are no such methods as Clear() or Add() in Grid class in WPF.

Comment: @vtvs On the `Grid` class, no.   It's on the `ColumnDefinitionCollection` and `RowDefinitionCollection` classes though which is what I have: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinitioncollection.clear.aspx